# Paypal accept only eur and dollars

Tags: paypal, currency, express-checkout

I'm confused with paypal documentation... I've setup recurring profiles for my application with express checkout... I want to only accept pyments in euros and dollars and if a buyer have a different currency , he must pay in one those two(and then I get the amount converted in the one he selected)

I configured my andbox account to accept eur and dollars and my code with express checkout I put EUR for euro and USD for dollar in currencycode...

But I don't understand this link

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_receive-outside

I thought that with my configuration payments will be automatically converted in USD or EUR because I don't let them chosing

for an example if a canadian chooses euros, I think that in his cart when he is logged the amount will be converted in euro and I'll get the amount in euro so I don't have to add canadian currency in currency I hold... Am I wrong or right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is paying you via express checkout then presumably you are sending the cart information to PayPal as part of the EC transaction flow. In this case you ALWAYS receive the payment in the currency you specify in the cart, regardless of any other factors. If buyers wish to pay using other currencies they will be converted to the currency of the cart.

The profile currency settings are really only relevant to situations where people can make open-ended payments to you of their own volition and definition. Or, these settings can also allow you to set up conditions where you let carts be defined in multiple currencies (e.g. maybe you have an EUR price, a USD price, and a GBP price), so the customer could buy goods with transactions denominated in any of these currencies, but you have PayPal automatically convert all the GBP transactions into EUR for you as they are deposited in your account balance.